# How to add another value to this PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
 $ing =  $_POST['ingredients'];
 $query = 'INSERT INTO Ingredients (ing) VALUES '; // base query
// dynamically build placeholders
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ing), '(?)'));
$final_query = $query . $placeholders;

$qry = $con->prepare($final_query); // prepare
 // bind the user names
$qry->execute($ing);
```

I want to add a $ID to the following query I have the value stored inside $ID but I just want to know how to adjust the INSERT query and add the $ID to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do insert a second value (`$ID`) into the database, you want to have your final query looking something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Ingredients (ing, id) VALUES ('ING_HERE', $ID)
```

---

To do this, if you change `$query` to this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO Ingredients (ing, id) VALUES ';
```

and if you append:

```
, $ID)
```

to the end of your query.

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you just tell me where I should append $ID ?

Comment: I would be more clear, but I'm not really sure what exactly `$placeholders` would look like, so could you please give an example of a value of `$placeholders` so I can clarify?

Comment: I have a form that contains a dynamic input field to add ingredients to a recipe so in the form I have name="ingredients[]" and I am using $placeholders to save each ingredient on a ROW in the database but I want to save the $ID together with each ingredient in the same ROW so I can fetch all the ingredients related to that recipe just by passing their common $ID. So that's why I want to add the $ID to that query